# Is the expression "taken out and shot" offensive?

Tags: expressions, idioms, word-usage

I refer to the expression "taken out and shot", used by [Daryl Gates](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1990-09-06-mn-983-story.html). I have seen this used on a couple of occasions in newspaper articles, and last year, such expression caused a lot of controversy after one of Trump's lawyers had used it.

What I'm after is whether or not this is a common expression and considered to be a hyperbole (or the equivalent of the phrase "to get shot of something" (get rid of someone), or else whether it is taken for its literal meaning (to kill someone).

Comment: Who knows what was in the mind of Chief Gates? I would call it [hyperbole](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hyperbole).

Comment: I corrected it, @WeatherVane.

Comment: I would think it says more about the person saying it, than something that would alarm the miscreants it is usually aimed at.

Comment: It's part of a larger condemnation: _X should be taken out and shot_, which is short for _X should be taken out (of this building) and X should be shot_. Presumably by the same people, or at least the same organization, though the passive leaves the agents unidentified in both cases, meaning that the statement is an encouragement to lynching or other amateur law enforcement. Most people find this offensive.

Comment: I believe the expression comes from death sentences, e.g. "to be taken out and shot" dating back at least 300 years.

Comment: It's not normally taken as a literal command to have someone killed, but when the political situation is charged, and mobs are storming public buildings, cops are killing people, people are shooting cops, or people are shooting politicians (as happens from time to time), such language could be considered inflammatory and likely to encourage somebody to resort to violence. Definitely not a nice thing to say. There are degrees of offensiveness, and it's not the worst thing, either.

Comment: "First said by Daryl Gates": hardly! A quick, non-exhaustive survey of Google Books turns up [this 1900 use](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Homiletic_Review/eZjNAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22taken+out+and+shot%22&pg=PA289&printsec=frontcover) as the first I can find that uses the phrase without connection to an actual execution or murder. [This 1954 use](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Government_in_Business/lvqWDA797P4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22taken+out+and+shot%22&pg=PA75&printsec=frontcover) is the earliest I can turn up to use it figuratively and off-handedly.

Comment: Also “to get shot of something” is *not* an expression at all, let alone one that means “get rid of someone”

Comment: And ... whether something is offensive or not is determined by the context.  The sentence “You look nice!” seems innocuous until you say it to your girlfriend’s sister while having said nothing to your girlfriend.

Comment: It is an expression, @Jim. Refer to [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+shot+of).

Comment: @DavidELU - Huh... Well, that’s a new one for me.  Maybe it’s chiefly British??

Comment: Precisely, @Jim.

Comment: I remember my mother once saying humorously that a tennis player 'wanted shooting' (deserved to be shot) if he didn't win his match. But this speaker obviously meant it seriously.

Comment: *Is the expression "taken out and shot" offensive?* No, it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

In 99.9% of cases, if spoken by an English speaker in a liberal democracy, this would be hyperbolic and metaphorical.

These expressions are used to express disapproval of someone's views, actions or failures but not necessarily serious disapproval. It can be said jokingly.

What "taken out and shot" means literally is that someone would be taken outside the building where they currently are and killed by being shot.

Given that it is a metaphor saying simply that someone should be shot would convey the same meaning but the reason why people say "taken out and shot" rather than just "shot" is that saying it in more words has a greater rhetorical effect. Similar expressions include:

"Shot at dawn" (referring to the historical practice of executing deserting soldiers  by firing squad at dawn).

"Hung, drawn, and quartered" (referring to a gruesome method of capital punishment meted out to traitors in England many centuries ago).

Another expression using a capital punishment metaphor is "It's not a hanging offence" (said about someone who did something wrong but not as seriously wrong as others are saying).

Are these expressions offensive? Any answer will inevitably be time and country specific. In rural Somerset we do not find these expressions offensive.